# Proof that the $r$'th factorial moment of a $Po(\lambda)$ random variable is $\lambda^r$?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, poisson-distribution, moments, moment-generating-function

If $X \sim Po(\lambda)$ then $E\left[X(X-1)\cdots(X-r+1)\right] = \lambda^r$.

Is there a straightforward way to see this without the use of moment generating functions?

I can get as far is $$E\left[X(X-1)\cdots(X-r+1)\right] = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} [k(k-1)\cdots (k-r+1)] \frac{\lambda^k e^{-\lambda}}{k!}$$ and noting that $k(k-1)\cdots (k-r+1) = k!/(k-r)!$ if $k\ge r$, but I can't see how to handle the case then $k<r$.

Comment: There is no "case $k\lt r$": those terms are zero.  The sum actually begins at $k=r$.  Since $k(k-1)\cdots(k-r+1)/k! = 1/(k-r)!$, all you have to do is factor out $\lambda^r$ and you're done.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is given in whubers comment, I will write it out with details.

First note that $\frac{x(x-1)\dots (x-r+1)}{x!} = \frac{1}{(x-r)!}$. Using that, 
$$
   \DeclareMathOperator{\E}{\mathbb{E}}
\E X(X-1) \dots (X-r+1) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty k(k-1)\dots (k-r+1) e^{-\lambda} \frac{\lambda^k}{k!} \\
= \lambda^r \sum_{k=r}^\infty e^{-\lambda}\frac{\lambda^{k-r}}{(k-r)!} \\
= \lambda^r \sum_{k=0}^\infty e^{-\lambda} \frac{\lambda^k}{k!} \\
= \lambda^r
$$